# Best SP design for my agenda

Tags: workflow

We are using SP 2013.  I've a SP site within an organization. I've to design and set up my particular site within the companies SP site. I only have the authorization to manage and design my site, and I do not have complete admin rights to the entire SP, only my section.

Here is what I will need to do with this site.  My office is Protocol and I will require different offices to access my SP page any time they have a Protocol function.  I've around 13 different offices that will need to access my SP13 site. Each office that has a protocol event will need to go into their particular folder/page on my SP 13 site where only those individuals assigned to that protocol event will be able to access it.  Those folders will be the working space between my office and the office holding the event.

There are some areas where all members will have access.  These areas will have all the master scripts, pictures, logos, and music.

What would be the best way to accomplish this.  I don't think the way I'm doing it now is correct.  I just have a bunch of folders with the offices names on it on one page.

Comment: Do you have the ability to Manage Permissions on your site? A good answer to your question will look significantly different depending on whether you can Manage Permissions directly, or are limited to assigning people to groups managed by the Site Collection Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong answer. What ever works for you - is the right choice.

There are some tips that can help you avoid some messy permission issues later however.

- If you use individual folders in a single library - and they have
  different permission set -than it would be beneficial to change those
  to separate libraries.
- If you need to collaborate with these group on more than just
  documents that get stored in a folder - then I would look at creating
  sub-sites.

Both of the above will give you more flexibility than using folders in a single library and permissions with be a bit easier to maintain going forward.  If you can' - try to use groups (SharePoint or Active Directory) to assign permission vs. just adding people directly.  I would also create a light "compliance" type page and document your sites and/or libraries and what the permissions should be.

With all that being said - the first thing I would do is go to the users using the site and ask them what they like and don't like.  That will help you decide on what if anything you should do.

Comment: One advantage to keeping the folders in a single library and setting different permissions per folder, instead of changing to separate libraries, is that you can use a single web part on a page (set to "show all items without folders") and each visitor will only see the content to which they have access. If you move each team's content to a separate library, you have to either create a separate web part to show each one (and all but one will say "nothing to display") or a separate page.

Comment: @DanHenderson that's where content roll up web parts (content query, content search, results search) come into play. you can also just create a specific search vertical page or combine the library views with custom list view. Like anything in SharePoint there multiple ways to solve a problem.

Comment: I suppose it's a bit of a trade-off, between the complexity of permissions management in a one-library approach, and the complexity of configuring content roll up web parts over that of configuring basic library view web parts in a multi-library approach. Since I don't find it any harder to manage permissions on multiple folders than on multiple libraries, I personally prefer the one-library approach.

Comment: Thank you, I Will try using only one library.  I am not sure how to do "can use a single web part on a page (set to "show all items without folders") and each visitor will only see the content to which they have access"  but I will give it a go.

Thank you for some advice

Comment: @skylinekiller put simply, you'd create folders in the library and name each after one office, setting permissions on each folder to only allow members of that office to view the folder. Then on a page you'd put a web part to show the documents library, customize the web part's view and under **Folders** choose `Show all items without folders`. You as the admin would then see all of the files; members of any one office would only see the files in that office's folder. Of course, you also have to ensure that your users know to follow this scheme and don't store documents in the root folder.

Comment: @skylinekiller see the Security subheading in [this article](http://blog.eastridge.net/when-should-you-use-folders-in-sharepoint) for more details on this practice.